# How git tracks commits in branches?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm new to git and i've been exploring it since last month. I understand it's very powerful as compared to other version control system. Yesterday i learnt that git branches are just files that store the head(SHA1) of the commit as listed in .git/refs/heads/ directory. my question is : How does git track the whole branch by just one commit(SHA1)? When i do :

```
 `git show {SHA1}`
```

it shows me that commit diff only. how does a commit knows which commit(s) is/are it's parents? When i do

```
`git rev-parse HEAD^1`
```

how does it shows me the commit which was before it. Initially i use to think a branch stores all of the commits involved in some specific order but now this fact has confused me totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commits are stored as a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). If you have no merge commits in your history, then going back from a single branch head is equivalent to a linked list.

You can see the full contents of a commit by using:

```
git cat-file commit HEAD
```

The `tree` line refers to the contents of that commit (e.g. as seen by `git ls-files`). Note that this is different than some other VCSes, which store deltas rather than trees.

The `parent` line(s), if any, are links to the previous commits.

---

Generally, if you want this kind of low-level information, you should use commands listed under `LOW-LEVEL COMMANDS (PLUMBING)` in `git`'s man page.